# ripgrep path pattern

Tags: ripgrep

I'd like ripgrep to search paths with the specified pattern. For e.g.

```
rg PATTERN --path REGEX
```

where PATTERN is the pattern to grep and REGEX is the path matching pattern.

I have scattered through the documentation and I am unsure if this functionality is baked in.

Comment: Lets be clear this is solvable using `rg -l PATTERN | grep -E REGEX` but I'd prefer to be more efficient and search only in files that match the pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `-g/--glob` flag, as [documented in the guide](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-filtering-globs). It uses globbing instead of regexes, but accomplishes the same thing in practice. For example:

```
rg PM_RESUME -g '*.h'
```

finds occurrences of `PM_RESUME` only in C header files in my checkout of the Linux kernel.

ripgrep provides no way to use a regex to match file paths. Instead, you should use xargs if you absolutely need to use a regex:

```
rg --files -0 | rg '.*\.h$' --null-data | xargs -0 rg PM_RESUME
```

Breaking it down:

- `rg --files -0` prints all of the files it would search, on stdout, delimited by `NUL`.
- `rg '.*\.h$' --null-data` only matches lines from the file list that end with `.h`. `--null-data` ensures that we retain our `NUL` bytes.
- `xargs -0 rg PM_RESUME` splits the arguments that are `NUL` delimited, and hands them to ripgrep, which precisely corresponds to the list of files matching your initial regex.

Handling `NUL` bytes is necessary for full correctness. If you don't have whitespace in your file paths, then the command is simpler:

```
rg --files | rg '.*\.h$' | xargs rg PM_RESUME
```

Comment: Can you add an example to demonstrate an exclude glob? I can't seem to get it to work: `rg --color=always 'regex_search' -g '!some/path/*' | tee rg.txt`. Files in path `some/path/*` are still being searched!

Comment: Nevermind! It works. The problem was it was finding patterns in my previous "rg.txt"-type output files. I just had to move or delete them.

Comment: This began working for me once I added `-.` (or `--hidden`)  since I was searching for files in `.github` folder

Answer (score 2):

You could use [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd):

```bsh
$ fd -p REGEX | xargs rg PATTERN
```

Comment: You may want to expand your answer to explain how to understand the `fd` option syntax.